# Powershell Joins

Tags: string, powershell, join

Im trying to join a number of elements of an array into a string using this;

```
$a = "h","e","l","l","o"
$b = [string]::join("", $a[0,1,2,3])
```

But I get a 'Missing ')' in method call' error.  The join documentation only mentions joining all the elements of an array, not elements at specific indexes. Can this be done?

Cheers

Andy

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Wrap the content of "$a[0,1,2,3]" with "$()" or "()"

```
PS> [string]::join("", $($a[0,1,2,3]))
hell
PS> [string]::join("", ($a[0,1,2,3]))
hell
```

-- Or --

you can use range operator ".."

```
PS> [string]::join("", $a[0..3])
hell
```

Answer (score 8):

```
PS > & {$ofs=""; "$($a[0,1,2,3])"}  
hell
```

Answer (score 1):

More idiomatic: use PowerShell's built-in join operator like this:

```
PS> $a[0,1,2,3] -join ""
hell
```